# Third party libraries in android studio website

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api

Is their any common site which have collection of all third party libraries in android. Similar to cocoa controls in iOS.

Actually I'm working on a cab booking application where I need to display annotation pinpoint to select pickup location while moving the maps(not a default one but must look pretty like what we see in today's travel apps), I need to customize the map, I need to display pickup and destination address in a separate nested layout which must be overlapped on map layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can look here for third party libraries

https://android-arsenal.com/

Comment: Already gone through it but didn't found a template which suite my requirement. I'm look for alternate one, please share me if any.

Comment: what are you looking for exactly